# ORA-08006: specified row no longer exists

Tags: oracle, informatica-powercenter

i have delete some duplicates in table which is paritioned using LIST for status Y and N. I have deleted duplicates which are active

```
delete from my_table partition(active_flag_y) where rowid = ( duplicate logic )
```

Post delete i started running my Informatica mapping which is having Update + insert logic.

While updating it is giving  me

> ORA-08006: specified row no longer exists

I am deleting using `rowid` but that `rowid` exists in my table.

Can someone help me with the solution

Answer (score 0):

> While updating it is giving me ORA-08006: specified row no longer exists

Include additional condition to `update`:

```
update your_table a
  set ...
-- add this:
where exists (select null
              from table_from_which_you_deleted_rows b
              where b.rowid = a.rowid 
             );
```

Next question is: what will you do with rows in `YOUR_TABLE` whose `ROWID` doesn't exist in a table you're referencing?

As you noticed, `ROWID` isn't the *best* piece of information you can rely on. Documentation says:

> If you delete and reinsert a row with the Import and Export utilities, for example, then its rowid may change. If you delete a row, then Oracle may reassign its rowid to a new row inserted later.

Comment: trying to update using informatica power center  UPDATE mytable SET ACTIVE_IND = 'N' WHERE ROWID = 'rowid' before it set to Y now trying to update to "N"